# Could not find gem 'gbarcode (>= 0) ruby' in https://github.com/ahx/gbarcode.git (at ruby1.9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and trying to configure my existing rails application, i am getting this error when i try to bundle install

```
Could not find gem 'gbarcode (>= 0) ruby' in https://github.com/ahx/gbarcode.git (at ruby1.9).
Source does not contain any versions of 'gbarcode (>= 0) ruby'
```

below is the code in my Gemfile.

```
gem 'gbarcode', :git => 'https://github.com/ahx/gbarcode.git', :branch => 'ruby1.9'
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong, can anyone suggest, thanks.

Comment: what ruby version you have?? because the rrepo say `"...Works on Ruby 1.9 (see ruby1.9 branch)..."`

Comment: ruby version is ruby 1.9.3p484